# How to add ellements in QJsonArray?

Tags: c++, json, qt

Good day. In my QT aplication, there is a need to store the value of structures of the same type in a JSON dictionary.
Values should be possible to add, read, change, delete. I know about the [JSON Save Game Example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcore-serialization-savegame-example.html) article, I tried to figure it out for a long time, I didn’t come to anything, I also surfed the forums with the same result.
The main problem is this:
Let's say I have the following structure:

```
struct Laptop{
    std::string name;
    int price;
    int year;
 };
```

And I want to store an array of such structures in a JSON dictionary. I am using the following code:

```
//filling structure
Laptop Ltemp = {"some name" , 1000, 2022}; 

//adding structure to JSON object
QJsonObject g;
g.insert("name", Ltemp.name.c_str());
g.insert("price", Ltemp.price);
g.insert("year", Gtemp.year);

//open and wtritingmy JSON
QFile file("path/to/myfile.json");
QByteArray jsonData = file.readAll();
QJsonDocument document = QJsonDocument::fromJson(jsonData);

QJsonObject object = document.object();
QJsonValue value = object.value("mydata");    
QJsonArray myArray= value.toArray();

myArray.removeAt(0);
myArray.append(g);

object.insert("mydata", myArray);

document.setObject(object);

//write to file
file.write(document.toJson());
file.close();
{
```

Expecting at the same time that when you re-apply the code, the data of the structure will be added to the same array, the key of which is "mydata", but in the end I have this:

```
    "mydata": [
        {
        "name": "some name",
        "price": 1000,
        "year": 2022
        }
    ],

    "mydata": [
        {
        "name": "some name",
        "price": 1000,
        "year": 2022
        }
    ]
 }
```

instead of

```
"mydata": [
    {
        "name": "some name",
        "price": 1000,
        "year": 2022
    },
    {
        "name": "some name",
        "price": 1000,
        "year": 2022
    }

]
```

Comment: Maybe this merge question will help: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64665582/how-to-merge-two-qjsonobjects-in-qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64665582/how-to-merge-two-qjsonobjects-in-qt) I am thinking this answer: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/66646700/487892](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66646700/487892)

Comment: the task is to add a JSON object to an already existing array..

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
QJsonObject g;

QJsonArray myArray; //[]
myArray.append(g);  //[{}]
myArray.append(g);  //[{},{}]
//add datas...

QJsonObject object;
object["mydata"] = myArray;

QJsonDocument document(object);
```

result

```
{ "mydata":[{},{}]}
```